# Where to find logs related to touchpad

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, kde

Distro: KDE Neon 5.12 (Ubuntu 16.04 based)
Laptop: Dell inspiron 3558

I am getting this weird bug where if I use smplayer or mpv or vlc for a while, touchpad tapping gets disabled, I am only able to move the cursor. Where can I find logs related to the touchpad, so that I might be able to submit a useful bug report (and hence in this place too)?